# Is criminal ransomware development allowed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, legal

[image]

[This little criminal has had his question up on our site for several hours.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729758/how-to-process-a-file-1-gb-or-10-gb-in-vb-net)

This isn't academic. It isn't a good question. It's some two-bit amateur criminal who needs our help in order to delete your family photos and charge you money to get them back.

Can we all agree this isn't something we want on the site?

---

Reason for asking: community moderation isn't very effective these days. Too much crap, too few tools for sorting it. However, moderators feel like they can't take unilateral action absent a policy endorsing it, so they havne't acted on this post.

**Can we agree that it's okay for moderators to delete explicitly-criminal posts?**

I don't want to be enabling these vile psychopaths.

---

In one of my first meta interactions on the network, in 2011, Joel and Jeff said:

> [Unless it is a clear call for warez, discussion of DRM should be given the benefit of the doubt.](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted)

I agree that discussion of code that could potentially be used for nefarious purposes is fine in many contexts. The field of information security couldn't exist without it. But when there's a clear criminal intent... that's the case we must not tolerate.

Comment: In the meanwhile, the post has been deleted, thanks to cross-posting in off-topic chat rooms. :P I'd still like a resolution here for future cases.

Comment: Should these questions be flagged as rude/abusive? Or just downvote and VTC?

Comment: I always have, and always will, down/close/delete any questions about malware development.  I really don't give a PHP how vociferously they claim that it's for white-hat 'learning purposes'.

Comment: @Jeremy come on, you can't go calling names at a specific user :P. I removed your "little criminal" and other ranty bits...

Comment: I agree this shouldn't be on the site, I mod flagged it and then @Andy just deleted my comments and moved on.

Comment: I agree, "little criminal" is bad.  OP may be a big criminal, or a right-sized criminal.

Comment: How many ransomware authors do you know that announce their product on a public web site?  It was just a dumb joke.  Do not intentionally deface a post, that is another slippery slope that is not funny in the least.  It just isn't necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant who cares if it's a joke or not?  Lets get rid of such posts, and the account, immediately.   I do agree with the 'no vandalism' aspect, however.

Comment: I don't understand why people need to defend the right to make personal attacks on people and then blame the mods or the community if the comments are deleted. Seriously. People need to really evaluate whether they're willing to abide by the [CoC](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). It's really time for the outrage of expecting some reasonable standard of behaviour to stop. Calling someone a "criminal" or any name is not acceptable.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I didn't pick it out of thin air: they were developing criminal software!

Comment: Ransomware isn't an interesting technical project that someone does for fun. It's technically boring.

Comment: @HansPassant The creator of silk road did it, and he's smarter than these guys...

Comment: @Jeremy irrelevant. If every time people called people the names that come into their brains, there'd be mayhem. Do you think people who don't say those things don't get upset? It's called biting your tongue and dealing with it in an adult fashion. You comment on the behaviour not the person. At least in the real world where I live, people are liable to get dragged into court if they call people names.

Comment: @Jeremy : How do you know the OP agrees with you? Maybe he's doing this just for practice? Maybe he's looking to become a white hat or an IT forensic in the future and wants to get a better insight in how ransomware can be made/operates? You have no idea what the OP's intent with this project is. Don't judge him too quickly.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Criminal wasn't chosen as an insult, it was descriptive.  "Two-bit" -- that actually was an insult

Comment: @Jeremy someone (not you) openly called the OP a criminal.

Comment: @Jeremy And "vile psychopaths"?  Also, asking how to encrypt a file isn't actually a criminal activity, last I checked.

Comment: @MartinJames : So we should just ban a user without even knowing what his intent of making the project was? I repeat [what I said to Jeremy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372144/is-ransomware-development-allowed-on-stack-overflow#comment618586_372144): What if he's doing this just to learn?

Comment: If he was doing it to learn he should have provided us an MCVE, instead of specifically contextualizing it for ransomware.

Comment: @VisualVincent Sure, you shouldn't judge the OP's intentions. But if the OP has any amount of common sense, he/she would give a lengthy explanation when the question has malware/criminal activity written all over it. It's like walking into the airport with an assault rifle and a bullet-proof vest. Sure you don't *know* what the person is trying to accomplish. But it's got bad news written all over it.

Comment: @Jeremy : Did you mean an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? (If not, please explain what MVCCE means.) He's new to the site, what if he didn't know what that was? What if he didn't think people would act so aggressively against him and his question?

Comment: @Mystical : Fair point. But things are a little different when done over the internet. Maybe he didn't actually think of adding a description, or maybe he didn't think anyone would care? Either way one could at least ask before starting to hate him.

Comment: @Mysticial The whole mess comes entirely from the method names that the person used for their methods.  The actual code being asked about is nothing more than the code to encrypt a file, something that there are *tons* of questions about, basically none of which are accused of being malicious.  They didn't need to justify why they needed to encrypt a file, they just needed to use a different method name to avoid the whole problem.

Comment: @VisualVincent umm... well, having thought it through, and considered all the implications, and possible effects in other areas, and the risk of side-effects... nope - I'll just start with the hate for all possible malware developers and then just carry on with it.

Comment: @Servy oh... please don't tell me the main site question is a "users don't read and thoroughtly analyse the questions before downvoting" troll.  If it is, it doesn't demonstrate anything useful:(

Comment: If it is a troll, it's like like walking into the airport with an assault rifle that has an empty clip and a bullet-proof vest where the kevlar plates have been replaced with cardboard.

Comment: @MartinJames : So white hats that make a living protecting, and trying to protect, large companies, banks, _your very bank account_, should just be hated because they had to temporarily hack/create malware in order to keep _your_ information safe? As Servy said: There are already plenty of questions out there about encrypting files where probably quite many had the intent of creating malware (and pretty much all can be easily used for the purpose), only in those cases _you didn't know_ that that's what they were trying to do.

Comment: @MartinJames I didn't say it's a good question.  The fact that there are tons and tons of other questions out there asking exactly the same thing (that aren't accused of being malicious) makes it a bad question because it's poorly researched.

Comment: @VisualVincent ...and I identify the white hats.... how?

Comment: @MartinJames : By asking them, if they haven't mentioned it already? But the truth is you can never know, which applies to everything. For instance: What if you thought I was a racist? You don't know for certain that I am, but you'll hate me for _thinking_ that I am a racist. How do you think that would make me feel if I found that out, and I weren't a racist? (for the record I'm not :) And even if I tell you that I am not, how will you know for sure?

Comment: My point is that always assuming the worst about people isn't a very healthy lifestyle. Not for you, nor for the people you assume the worst about.

Comment: @VisualVincent prosecutor: "So, Mr James, your defense is that you thought that the obviously-malicious code you helped develop was for a benign purpose?  You are an experienced software professional!   Do you really expect the judge/jury to believe that?  I ask that Mr. James be held equally liable with the other defendants".

Comment: LOL!!!  'By asking them'.  I should spend all that time and effort on paying a lawyer to go visit them and get a signed statement that the code will not be used for nefarious purposes?

Comment: @VisualVincent 'always assuming the worst about people isn't a very healthy lifestyle' lol, it depends where you are.  In a large city, at 0200, on a Saturday, it's a really healthy to avoid groups of people in dark alleys.  The web is always dark, just some parts are darker than others;)

Comment: @MartinJames : If the OP told you convincing stuff or gave you convincing evidence that this was for a good purpose you wouldn't be held liable as you were doing it in good faith (at least, this is how it works in Sweden). Still though, if you are unsure of the intent you can always ask, and if the OP replies: _"I do this because I want to make easy money of of people_", then sure, go ahead and hate all you want!

Comment: @MartinJames : _"I should spend all that time and effort on paying a lawyer to go visit them and get a signed statement that the code will not be used for nefarious purposes?"_ - No, but by simply asking them. As I said if the OP gave convincing evidence/statements, in Sweden you wouldn't be held liable since you would think it was for a good cause. Compared to late dark nights in a large city, asking someone on the internet actually doesn't hurt you. ;)

Comment: @MartinJames : Good talk! You've made some very good and interesting points, and I like to hear things from other people's perspective! We both want to help other people in some way or another. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's allowed. In fact, one of the actual *real* questions asked by a criminal is still on the site:

[Destroying a specific session in Code Igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563675/destroying-a-specific-session-in-code-igniter)

The question you linked is a technical question, asking about a coding problem. That's what we are here for.

---

As for "enabling"...don't answer or help if you don't want to. The community closed and deleted the question just fine. Sure it didn't take place immediately, but honestly, flagging for moderator attention isn't what brought the question to my attention either. I noticed it in one of the cross posted chat rooms.

Which brings me to another aspect of this particular question: Handling the questions correctly. If you don't think a question is appropriate, flag it. Don't get in an edit war. Don't berate the user. Just vote to close an move on. Before I mentioned something in the comments, this post had a single close vote, but had been edited several times to try and hide the content.

Comment: I agree, no edit war, no comments, just exterminate the user account immediately.

Comment: How about we focuss all the "unwelcomeness" on to these types of users? It's better for us, and it's better for them.

Comment: I feel like this response misses a major distinction between the two threads. One thread makes very clear it's being used for malicious purposes - it says "ransomware" right there in the code. The other does not - and arguably never *was* used maliciously (or at least, no more maliciously than their Postfix install...). Making a bullet is a different act than shooting someone, even if both involve a bullet.

Comment: "arguably" this wasn't used to do anything malicious either. Functions can be named anything. I didn't miss the distinction between the two. If you are going with that bullet analogy, the question here, for both of them, was at the making a bullet phase.

Comment: @Andy If we had a "Gunsmiths StackExchange", surely "I'd like to know how to make my own bullets" would be treated differently than "I'd like to know how to make my own bullets to assassinate a head of state"? In one, intent is very clear.

Comment: @ceejayoz Arguing by analogy is not a good way to argue. In this example, the "make a bullet" is the question being discussed in this meta question. "shooting someone" is the question that was involved in an actual criminal case, where someone was convicted of a crime. In any case, I've stated my opinion, if you disagree, vote how you wish. I encourage you to post a response on the linked duplicate if you want to expand on that vote.